# Construct a basis of the matrix elements in the space $\mathbb{C}[S_{3}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

Construct a basis of the matrix elements in the space $\mathbb{C}[S_{3}]$.

If the definition of the Spaces of Matrix Elements is as given below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the answer of the question at the back of Vinberg book (Linear representations of groups) is given below:

[image]

But I do not know how is this the answer, could anyone explain how one element of this table calculated? and what is the number 11 in the second subscript of T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the definition involves a representation of the group.

From context, $T_1$, $T_2$, and $T_3$ are the irreducible representations of $S_3$.  The first two are one dimensional and the last is two dimensional.  $T_{k,ij}(g)$ in the table gives the $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix of $T_k(g)$ written in the given basis.

Comment: and how the basis is constructed?

Comment: The space is spanned by  the elements $T_{ij}$ by definition, so just listing the $T_{ij}$ like this gives you a basis.

Comment: So could you please tell me how is the element say $\bar \omega$ calculated?

Comment: you are inspiring ..... I looked at your highly voted question ....... you insert the hope in many people Daniel ..... I hope to be ike you

Comment: I see you accepted the answer.  Do you get it now?

Comment: No I am still waiting for your response

Comment: Well, with the definition you've given, you have to start from a representation of $S_3$, so presumably you'd be starting from the representation $T_3$, and if you know what $T_3$ is then you know where the $\omega$ comes from.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to read further along in the book to answer this question.  Do you know about the irreducible representations of the symmetric group?

Comment: I am reading more now and if I have any difficulties I will inform you

Comment: so sorry for this trivial question but what are the standard representations of $S_{3}$ are they $1, \mathbb{C^1}, \mathbb{C^2}$?

Comment: There are two different actions on $\mathbb{C}$.  One is given by $g \cdot x = x$ and one is given by $g \cdot x = (\operatorname{sign} g)x$.  There is also an irreducible representation on $\mathbb{C}^2$ which would take longer to describe.  This should be in your book.

Comment: Now I to some extent understand the irreducible representations of $S_{3}$ .... but I do not understand why $k=3$ appears 4 times in the first column ..... could you please explain this for me?

Comment: should I have the character table of $S_{3}$ in front of me to construct this table?